# Simultaneous Audio and Video Recording on iPhone 4S

Tags: audio-recording, video-recording, video-editing

I was trying to video record a Christmas greeting on an iPhone 4S using the switch function on the camera so I can frame myself properly.  I am able to record the video but can't figure out how to record the sound track at the same time.  I loaded both iMovies and iTalk but it appears that marrying voice and video tracks require post-recording editing.  Is there any way to record audio and video simultaneously?